# Calculation using different Textboxes of Reactive Form in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a Form In Angular-9 Application, contains few **TextBoxes** and My **FormGroup** object looks as below:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.initForm();
  this.conditionalValidation();
}

initForm() {
    this.formCreateNewPlan = this.fb.group({
      channel: new FormControl('', { validators: [Validators.required], updateOn: 'blur' }),
      template: new FormControl('', { validators: [Validators.required], updateOn: 'blur', }),
      name: new FormControl('', {
        validators: [
          Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.pattern(RegexPatterns.AlphaNumeric),], updateOn: 'blur'
      }),
      description: new FormControl('', {
        validators: [Validators.pattern(RegexPatterns.AlphaNumeric)], updateOn: 'blur'
      }),
      planBasis: new FormControl('', { validators: [Validators.required], updateOn: 'blur' }),
      startDate: new FormControl('', { validators: [Validators.required], updateOn: 'blur' }),
      endDate: new FormControl('', { validators: [Validators.required], updateOn: 'blur' }),
      circulation: [null],
      percentResponse: [null],
      orders: [null],
      units: [null],
      unitsPerOrder: [null],
      revenuePerOrder: [null],
      revenue: [null],
      unusualDemandRevenue: [null],
    });
  }
```

Also, I'm doing Conditional Validation as shown below:

```
conditionalValidation() {
    const circulation = this.formCreateNewPlan.get('circulation');
    const percentResponse = this.formCreateNewPlan.get('percentResponse');

    const orders = this.formCreateNewPlan.get('orders');
    const units = this.formCreateNewPlan.get('units');
    const unitsPerOrder = this.formCreateNewPlan.get('unitsPerOrder');
    const revenuePerOrder = this.formCreateNewPlan.get('revenuePerOrder');
    const revenue = this.formCreateNewPlan.get('revenue');
    const unusualDemandRevenue = this.formCreateNewPlan.get('unusualDemandRevenue');

    this.formCreateNewPlan.get('channel').valueChanges.subscribe(c => {
      if (c == "46") {
        circulation.setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(RegexPatterns.Numeric)]);
        percentResponse.setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(RegexPatterns.Numeric)]);
      } else {
        circulation.clearValidators();
        percentResponse.clearValidators();
      }

      if (c == "64") {
        orders.setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(RegexPatterns.Numeric)]);
        units.setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(RegexPatterns.Numeric)]);
        unitsPerOrder.setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(RegexPatterns.Decimal)]);
        revenuePerOrder.setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(RegexPatterns.Decimal)]);
        revenue.setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(RegexPatterns.Decimal)]);
        unusualDemandRevenue.setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(RegexPatterns.Decimal)]);
      } else {
        orders.clearValidators();
        units.clearValidators();
        unitsPerOrder.clearValidators();
        revenuePerOrder.clearValidators();
        revenue.clearValidators();
        unusualDemandRevenue.clearValidators();
      }

      circulation.updateValueAndValidity();
      percentResponse.updateValueAndValidity();

      orders.updateValueAndValidity();
      units.updateValueAndValidity();
      unitsPerOrder.updateValueAndValidity();
      revenuePerOrder.updateValueAndValidity();
      revenue.updateValueAndValidity();
      unusualDemandRevenue.updateValueAndValidity();
    });
  }
```

Here, I want to do some calculation based on **TextBox** values (on change):

1. Orders – This is a calculated field when catalog is the channel (Circulation x Percent Response).
2. Revenue - This is a calculated field (Orders x Revenue / Order).
3. Units / Order – This is a calculated field (Units / Orders)

How to do this in Reactive Form? Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I prefer that you use (input) event on the form fields that you want to use their values to make the calculations.

i.e

> .html

```
<input type="number" matInput (input)="calculateValues()" formControlName="circulation" />
<input type="number" [min]="0" [max]="100" matInput (input)="calculateValues()" formControlName="percentResponse" />
```

> .ts

```
    calculateValues() {
      // check the fields required to make the calculations to avoid NaN errors
      if(this.formCreateNewPlan.value.circulation && this.formCreateNewPlan.value.circulation) {
        // patch the values on the form
        this.formCreateNewPlan.patchValue({
           orders: +this.formCreateNewPlan.value.circulation * +this.formCreateNewPlan.value.circulation
        });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try `setValue()`?

```
orders.setValue(circulation.value * percentResponse.value); // using your consts here. Use this.formCreateNewPlan.get('orders').setValue() otherwise.
```

as FormGroups default to string, you might `parseInt` the values (dependent on whether your input is specified as `type="number"`.

In order to toggle the calculation upon input change, you can either use the template `(change)`on the input itself, like:

```
// .html
<input formControlName="order" (change)="recalculateOrder()">

// .ts
public recalculateOrder() {
  this.formCreateNewPlan.get('orders').setValue(
    this.formCreateNewPlan.get('circulation').value *
    this.formCreateNewPlan.get('percentResponse').value
  );
}
```

or `(ngModelChange)` if you need the recalculation upon every keypress (I assume it is keyUp).

if you want to directly display the changed value, a changeDetectorRef.detectChanges() could be necessary. (injectable from angular/core)

btw a `formCreateNewPlan.updateValueAndValidity()` should do [as stated in the docmentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateValueAndValidity)

[image: update value and validity documentation]